# Flutter: 3 Screen registration forms, How to get all the user inputs from all the screens

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I followed a UI design tutorial which built 3 screen user registration UI containing the Register Account, Complete Profile and OTP page

Now i want to retrive all the user inputs from the Registration Screen and Complete Profile Screen then save it to firebase once the OTP code is confirmed

i have tried using

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) => CompleteProfileScreen(email: email, password: password ...
   ),                                           
  ),
 );
```

which seems not to be the right way but i still kept getting errors

complete Codes BELLOW

Registration Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/custom_surfix_icon.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/form_error.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/screens/complete_profile/complete_profile_screen.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';

class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpFormState createState() => _SignUpFormState();
}

class _SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email;
  String password;
  String conform_password;
  bool remember = false;
  final List<String> errors = [];

  void addError({String error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.add(error);
      });
  }

  void removeError({String error}) {
    if (errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.remove(error);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildConformPassFormField(),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continue",
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                // if all are valid then go to success screen
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, CompleteProfileScreen.routeName);
                // // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                // //   return CompleteProfileScreen(
                // //       var1: email, var2: password, var3: conform_password);
                // // }
                // ));
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildConformPassFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => conform_password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.isNotEmpty && password == conform_password) {
          removeError(error: kMatchPassError);
        }
        conform_password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if ((password != value)) {
          addError(error: kMatchPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Confirm Password",
        hintText: "Re-enter your password",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removeError(error: kShortPassError);
        }
        password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (value.length < 8) {
          addError(error: kShortPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        hintText: "Enter your password",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Complete Registration Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/custom_surfix_icon.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/form_error.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/screens/otp/otp_screen.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/screens/sign_up/components/sign_up_form.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';

class CompleteProfileForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompleteProfileFormState createState() => _CompleteProfileFormState();
}

class _CompleteProfileFormState extends State<CompleteProfileForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final List<String> errors = [];
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String phoneNumber;
  String address;
  String phonePrefix = "+234";
  String phoneNumberComplete;

  void addError({String error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.add(error);
      });
  }

  void removeError({String error}) {
    if (errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.remove(error);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildFirstNameFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildLastNameFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPhoneNumberFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildAddressFormField(),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "continue",
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, OtpScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildAddressFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (newValue) => address = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kAddressNullError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kAddressNullError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Address",
        hintText: "Enter your phone address",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon:
            CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Location point.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPhoneNumberFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
      onSaved: (newValue) => phoneNumber = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPhoneNumberNullError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPhoneNumberNullError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Phone Number",
        hintText: "eg: 08033333333",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Phone.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildLastNameFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (newValue) => lastName = newValue,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Last Name",
        hintText: "Enter your last name",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/User.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildFirstNameFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      onSaved: (newValue) => firstName = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kNamelNullError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kNamelNullError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "First Name",
        hintText: "Enter your first name",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/User.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OTP Screen: //Where i want to get all the variables from Registration and Complete Registration Sceens

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/screens/home/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:signuptest/size_config.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';

class OtpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const OtpForm({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OtpFormState createState() => _OtpFormState();
}

class _OtpFormState extends State<OtpForm> {
  FocusNode pin2FocusNode;
  FocusNode pin3FocusNode;
  FocusNode pin4FocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pin2FocusNode = FocusNode();
    pin3FocusNode = FocusNode();
    pin4FocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    pin2FocusNode.dispose();
    pin3FocusNode.dispose();
    pin4FocusNode.dispose();
  }

  void nextField(String value, FocusNode focusNode) {
    if (value.length == 1) {
      focusNode.requestFocus();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.15),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: getProportionateScreenWidth(60),
                child: TextFormField(
                  autofocus: true,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: otpInputDecoration,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    nextField(value, pin2FocusNode);
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: getProportionateScreenWidth(60),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: pin2FocusNode,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: otpInputDecoration,
                  onChanged: (value) => nextField(value, pin3FocusNode),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: getProportionateScreenWidth(60),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: pin3FocusNode,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: otpInputDecoration,
                  onChanged: (value) => nextField(value, pin4FocusNode),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: getProportionateScreenWidth(60),
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: pin4FocusNode,
                  obscureText: true,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  decoration: otpInputDecoration,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    if (value.length == 1) {
                      pin4FocusNode.unfocus();
                      // Then you need to check is the code is correct or not
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.15),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continue",
            press: () {
              //Where to send the user after Signing Up
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.routeName);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a provider when managing data in Flutter through multiple screens. Providers allow you to store all of your important data along with any related functions within just one class which can then easily be accessed in any of your files.

For more info concerning providers, please look [here](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).